# Trying to open a Excel file dropped into an S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to open an Excel file dropped into an S3 bucket. I'm not sure how to go about this, however the following code is giving me an error.

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket=s3.Bucket('mybucket')
rawstream = io.StringIO()
csvwriter = csv.writer(rawstream, delimiter="\t",doublequote=True, 
strict=True)

for key in bucket.objects.all():
    if key.key.startswith('dropzone'):
        if 'Air' in key.key:
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook(key.key)
            sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
```

I'm getting the error:
[Errno 2] No such file or directory:

The full path of the excel file is
s3://mybucket/dropzone/nike_Air.xlsx

Answer (score 0):

`open_workbook` is expecting to open a file on a file system, not an object in an S3 bucket.  You'll need to first download the file to the local file system.  This would be something like:

```
for key in bucket.objects.all():
    if key.key.startswith('dropzone'):
        if 'Air' in key.key:
            with open('local_file_name', 'wb') as f:
                s3.download_fileobj('mybucket', key.key, f)
            wb = xlrd.open_workbook('local_file_name')
            sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)
```

Comment: This is running as a lambda function, does this change things?

Comment: No code change required with AWS Lambda, but you can only save files in the `/tmp/` directory.

Comment: Working.. Thanks!